# Who is responsible for a project's security requirements?

Tags: requirements

The product owner is responsible for the functional requirements, but who is responsible for the security requirements?  Security requirements are thought of as nonfunctional requirements but is this always the case?  Would the responsibility for NFRs fall under the same umbrella as security requirements?

Comment: It depends on the company. If you work for a financial institution, there is often an entire department for it, or it could be part of a larger Risk & Compliance team. And yes, security requirements are considered NFRs, but not all NFRs are security requirements.

Answer (score 5):

The risk owner is responsible.

Security exists to mitigate risks. The requirements, then, need to be defined and governed by the risk owner.

Is security always an NFR? The question itself should suggest its own answer: "it depends". It depends on the requirements, whether or not security is a "function", and what "NFR" means to your teams. Often NFR means it is a low-priority, low-resourced annoyance to satisfy some 3rd party (cue the interns). So, even if it might technically be an NFR in some contexts, you might want to elevate it to give it the attention it needs, as directed by the risk owner.

Comment: I asked because in this course I took the explanation was nebulous.  The instructor mentioned that "security is everyone's business" and that security requirements could come from stakeholders in all directions.

Comment: The person *responsible* is the risk owner. Stakeholders from all directions can have their own needs and expectations.

Comment: I think the "security is everyone's business" comes from the context that every individual in an organization has a responsibility to protect their customers and own information. This is a slogan commonly use in Security Awareness. The idea is to drive a "security" driven culture.